# how to class for form in listbox data

Tags: c#, windows, forms

class1 in method with the result that I create in one class I want to write data to the listbox. I wrote the code does not work, but it seems empty listbox. How do I write the code?

```
class Class1
{
    Form1 form = new Form1();

    public void Result()
    {
        form.listBox1.Items.Add("hello");
    }
}
```

}

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 btn_class = new Class1();
        btn_class.Result();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: A form *is* a class. Not sure what you are trying to do, but the code for `Class1` is creating a different form1 instance which is never shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you creating a new instance of a form and assigning the new item to that Listbox.
You could give your Form as a parameter to solve the problem

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 btn_class = new Class1(this);
        btn_class.Result();
    }

}

class Class1
{
    private Form1 _form;
    public Class1(Form1 form)
    {
        this._form = form;
    }


    public void Result()
    {
        _form.listBox1.Items.Add("hello");
    }
}
```